# Read a single word from a string and set as a variable value in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a need for a simple function to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

select_word() {

echo "Enter a string."
read STRING

## User enters "This is a string."

## Here will be the command to set each word to the below variables.

WORD_1=
WORD_2=
WORD_3=
WORD_4=

echo -e "Word 1 is: $WORD_1.\n Word 2 is: $WORD_2.\n"
echo -e "Word 3 is: $WORD_3.\n Word 4 is: $WORD_4.\n"
}
```

I am wanting to avoid using external tools such as sed or awk. Looking for bash builtin functions to use in order to pull each word from the string and set that word as a variable value. I will later use "wc" to count the number of characters in each word. I already know how to do that, I just need to know the bash method to pulling a word from user input strings.

If this question is a duplicate, I apologize as I could not find this specific question.

Comment: Do you need those words to be in the `WORD_n` variables?

Comment: Yes. If the user input is, "This is a string." Then I need WORD_1="This" WORD_2="is" WORD_3="a" WORD_4="string" in this format. This is crucial to the rest of the script which will use the character count of each word to perform specific functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` can split the string itself.

```
read -r WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4
```

If you enter fewer than 4 words, the last variable(s) will be set to empty strings. If you enter *more* than 4 words, `WORD4` will be the rest of the string, not just the 4th word.

You can also split the string into an array, if you don't know how many words will be entered ahead of time.

```
read -a words
WORD1=${words[0]}
WORD2=${words[1]}
WORD3=${words[2]}
WORD4=${words[3]}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I coded before you answered. I have the string being split into variable "values" and before I have empty variables, I perform a string word count to see how many words are present in the string, I use that number to set how many values I need created in the array. So it works out perfectly for my intent. The user input strings are going to be anywhere from a few words to entire paragraphs. So what I have figured out is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the space delimited `$STRING` into an array, and then reference each array element in `$WORD_n` variables:

```
   WORDS=($STRING)

   WORD_1=${WORDS[0]}
   WORD_2=${WORDS[1]}
```

Of with `set -f`, which will disable globing (e.g. changing `*` to list of files in current directory):

```
   set -f
   WORDS=($STRING)
   set +f

   WORD_1=${WORDS[0]}
   WORD_2=${WORDS[1]}
```

Comment: Will this ignore spaces between each word in the string?

Comment: @YokaiSeishinkage Yes, it splits the string on the spaces

Comment: This subjects `$STRING` to glob expansion as well.

Comment: This is definitely not the right way to proceed. See chepner's answer for the proper way to achieve that.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf actually **krzyk's** original suggestion, before his edits, did exactly what I wanted. And on my system it runs faster than using the set -f method.

Comment: @YokaiSeishinkage The version with `set -f` runs slower or makes the output wrong?

Comment: Your original answer runs faster on my system yes. The output is still correct.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to be independent of the number of words typed, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

select_word() {

echo "Enter a string."
read STRING

## User enters "This is a string."

GENERAL_VAR_NAME="WORD_"

## Here will be the command to set each word to the below variables.
# Split string into an array, default delimiter whitespace
STRING=( $STRING )

# Number of array elements: ${#STRING[@]}
for (( c=1; c<=${#STRING[@]}; c++ ))
do
        #echo -e "WORD $c is: ${STRING[$c]}"
        NEW_WORD=`echo -e $GENERAL_VAR_NAME${c}`
        printf -v $NEW_WORD "${STRING[$c]}"
done

# Check the output
for (( i=1; i<=${#STRING[@]}; i++ )); do
        echo "WORD_$i is $WORD_$i"
done

}

select_word
```

Comment: Your array logic is sound, I guess you got hit for the `GENERAL_VAR_NAME="WORD_"` creativity, or the lack of clarity reusing `STRING` as an array w/out unsetting first. (sometimes you just never know why a downvote happens if the kiddos doing it lack the integrity to stop and leave a comment related to their action. To make your point after `array=( $STRING )`, you could have simply shown that word splitting occurred into separate elements of the array with `declare -p array` and remove the rest of the code. Then the point would be crystal clear.